# I'm going to do a project on braid groups, and I'm looking for recommendations on books about braid groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, braid-groups

I asked my advisor (which is not the professor I will be doing the project with) about this project, and he recommended that I read some of Artin's material on braid groups because as my advisor put it: "It seems that many mathematicians later on didn't quite 'get it'". Should I delve into Artin's stuff or should I instead study some other books on this topic?

EDIT: (more info) I don't know much about braid groups besides the very basics, but it seems very interesting and that's why I want to do this project. It doesn't require previous knowledge of braid groups. We are going to study the braid groups of affine type (whatever that means) so maybe a book which covers that eventually will be good. My background is in algebra, I have taken courses in rings and modules, now I'm taking galois theory.

Comment: What are you specifically interested in about braid groups and what is your background? I could try to offer suggestions based on that.

Comment: See my edit for an answer to your comment

Comment: Hi @Auclair, thanks for updating your question! I think http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387338415 is a very good reference for braid groups (containing some representation theory in the middle/later chapters). Note that there is a story regarding braid groups and knots and links, which is worth knowing, but not particularly relevant if you are primarily interested in representation theory in the short term. (This story allows you to use the representation theory of the braid group to define knot and link invariants.) Thus, you could omit most of Chapter 1 and all of Chapter 2.

Comment: Have a look at the book if you get the time, and please let me know (based on the table of contents) whether or not it seems suitable for your current interests. Otherwise, I can dig up some other references. I think having some basic knowledge of braid groups would be helpful in any case, no matter which direction you choose, and this book seems suitable for the purpose of acquiring a basic knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

you can see for example:
1-Braids, links and mapping class groups of J.Birman
2-A Study of braids by B kurbita and K Murasugi
Two good books in the the field of Braids.